# Natbib giving citation undefined

Tags: natbib

I have been doing citations using natbib without bibtex and manually entering citations. I keep getting an issue when compiling stating "Citation 'all citations' on page # undefined on input line #"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\title{my title}
\author{my name}
\date{some date}
\maketitle

\section*{section title}
some text some more text and more \citep{hooper05} and then more \citep{hobbs92}. 
And last but not least more and more text \citep{da05}.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[Daehler,(2005)]{da05} CSE citation here
\bibitem[Hobbs \& Huennke(1992)]{hobbs92} CSE citation here
\bibitem[Hooper et al.(2005)]{hooper05} CSE citation here



\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

This is an example of the full document used. When I try and place my citations in alphabetical order the output is more and includes "Citation '(all citations)' on page # undefined on input line #". At the moment I only have three citations and am intending on including more and have them in alphabetical order. When i rearrange in the order i placed the citations in the text it compiles just fine.

Comment: Works for me once I correct the typo at the end of the bibliography environment. At least, I don't get complaints about undefined citations. I don't get any labels in the bibliography either.

Comment: Yea I rearranged and placed last citation on top, still not alphabetical, it works, however when i rearrange all i get the complaints again. The typo was also fixed.

Comment: @AlexanderCerra: I don't receive any problems. Admittedly, I removed `mathtools`, `float` and `graphicx`, since they have nothing to do with this. Could you please provide the problem code and then the code that compiles without problem? I can't seem to replicate your problem as it stands. Also, why not just let `bibtex` take care of the sorting?

Comment: So the code you posted does not reproduce the problem? You should post an MWE which produces the problem. No point posting code which works fine. I don't know why it would not be alphabetical D -> Hob -> Hoo so, as included, the list will be alphabetical and since that code works, I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Is there any point in specifying a bibliography style if you are not using bibTeX? The `.bst` files are not LaTeX's business as far as I know.

Comment: @Werner. I have graphicx, math tools, and float as packages for other purposes in the assignment. Also admitting that I have always used graphicx just because I have always though that was necessary. Also the problem is exactly as above. There are more sections that have formulas and figures/tables.

Comment: Also @cfr when i place the code in the format below, with all the same coding,     
 
 \bibitem[Hooper et al.(2005)]{hooper05} CSE citation here \bibitem[Hobbs \& Huennke(1992)]{hobbs92} CSE citation here  \bibitem[Daehler,(2005)]{da05} CSE citation here      i dont get issues but natbib doest not place in alphabetical order just the order i placed. when i stated that i rearranged and put     \bibitem[Daehler,(2005)]{da05} CSE citation here before the rest it again goes in that order.

Comment: Which format? Below what? The code you have posted in your question compiles fine. It does not reproduce any problem. This is true even when I add back in those packages which are entirely irrelevant. (This isn't surprising since they are irrelevant but I checked just in case.)

Comment: ***We are testing the code you posted in the question and it works for us.*** So, the problem lies elsewhere. Add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and post the versions of things you are using. (Take out `graphicx` etc. before you do this as they are just unnecessary clutter.)

Comment: @cfr i am new to this site and new to latex its taking me a while to figure this out. i apologize for any inconvenience i am causing. i placed \listfiles as you stated and it works perfectly

Comment: however @cfr when i tried the example i placed, without the clutter of the other packages i still got the same warnings "Citation '(all citations)' on page # undefined on input line #" for all citations but i place \listfiles and it worked. maybe its the R stdio version i am using on mac

Comment: That's OK. It is fairly normal. But: what?! Adding `\listfiles` cannot possibly cause it to work. All that command does is provides information about the packages and class you are using. It isn't a fix. It is merely diagnostic. Like an X-ray. If you had a broken arm before, the X-ray won't make it better!

Comment: @cfr anyway i can show you? stackexhange won't let me chat. but yea for some reason it solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is typeset the bibliography *manually*. This is manageable, but then you have to do all the sorting yourself. Here is the output when compiling a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\begin{document}

\section*{section title}
some text some more text and more \citep{hooper05} and then more \citep{hobbs92}. 
And last but not least more and more text \citep{da05}.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
  \bibitem[Daehler,(2005)]{da05} Daehler, CSE citation here
  \bibitem[Hooper et al.(2005)]{hooper05} Hooper, CSE citation here
  \bibitem[Hobbs \& Huennke(1992)]{hobbs92} Hobbs, CSE citation here
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

If you now switch around some of the bibliography items, LaTeX will just again typeset it as is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\begin{document}

\section*{section title}
some text some more text and more \citep{hooper05} and then more \citep{hobbs92}. 
And last but not least more and more text \citep{da05}.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
  \bibitem[Hobbs \& Huennke(1992)]{hobbs92} Hobbs, CSE citation here
  \bibitem[Hooper et al.(2005)]{hooper05} Hooper, CSE citation here
  \bibitem[Daehler,(2005)]{da05} Daehler, CSE citation here
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

---

You mention that you'll be adding references to the bibliography, making it grow. Then I suggest you use the power of BibTeX to actually sort it for you. For that, you can use the following template as a base (I used the following, perhaps fake, references: [Hobbs & Huennke](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1523-1739.1992.06030324.x/abstract), [Daehler](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1526-100X.2005.00047.x/abstract) and [Hooper, et al](http://www.imperial.ac.uk/people/b.blackman/publications.html?id=&keywords=&limit=15&page=1&respub-action=search.html&person=true)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{source.bib}
@article {hobbs92,
  author = {Hobbs, Richard J. and Huenneke, Laura F.},
  title = {Disturbance, Diversity, and Invasion: Implications for Conservation},
  journal = {Conservation Biology},
  volume = {6},
  number = {3},
  publisher = {Blackwell Science Inc},
  issn = {1523-1739},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1046/j.1523-1739.1992.06030324.x},
  doi = {10.1046/j.1523-1739.1992.06030324.x},
  pages = {324--337},
  year = {1992},
}
@article {da05,
  author = {Daehler, Curtis C. and Goergen, Erin M.},
  title = {Experimental Restoration of an Indigenous Hawaiian Grassland after Invasion by Buffel Grass (Cenchrus ciliaris)},
  journal = {Restoration Ecology},
  volume = {13},
  number = {2},
  publisher = {Blackwell Science Inc},
  issn = {1526-100X},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1526-100X.2005.00047.x},
  doi = {10.1111/j.1526-100X.2005.00047.x},
  pages = {380--389},
  keywords = {Cenchrus ciliaris, grassland, Hawaii, Heteropogon contortus, invasive grasses, priority effects},
  year = {2005},
}
@article{hooper05,
  author = {Hooper, PA and Blackman, BRK and Dear, JP},
  pages = {3564--3576},
  title = {The mechanical behaviour of poly(vinyl butyral) at different strain magnitudes and strain rates},
  volume = {47},
  year = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\begin{document}

\section*{section title}
some text some more text and more \citep{hooper05} and then more \citep{hobbs92}. 
And last but not least more and more text \citep{da05}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{source}

\end{document}
```

So, instead of manually creating a `thebibliography` environment with `\bibitem`s, you create a `.bib` file and input the contents using a specific BibTeX syntax, and include this bibliography using `\bibliography{<bib source>}`.

Compile the above use pdfLaTeX, followed by a compiling using BibTeX, then twice again using pdfLaTeX and the output would be:

[image]

Note how, even though we cited in the order Hooper, Hobbs, Daehler and `source.bib` has the order Hobbs, Daehler, Hooper, the output has the *alphabetical* order Dahler, Hobbs, Hooper. That's because BibTeX read the citation information as well as a `.bst` (referenced using `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` - `plainnat.bst`) and sorted the contents accordingly (outside of LaTeX). BibTeX also created a `.bbl` file, which is then included with your call to `\bibliography{<bib source>}`.